# Localhost page downloading error

Tags: php, firefox, localhost

In the context of a course on PHP, I downloaded correctly the WAMP package, but at the time of opening the localhost homepage, I got the following error message :
Page downloading error. Connection failed. Firefox cannot connect to the server at the address localhost. I run Apache 2.4.17, MySQL 5.7.9, PHP 5.6.16 and 7.0.0 versions.

Thanks for Helping.

Patrick Fédida

Answer (score 0):

you must start the apache service first before you can enter localhost.
if it's already started then try using the following:
http://localhost:80/
http://localhost:8080/